# how to map a config class to application.properties in springboot in junit Test class?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit5

i want to map a config class to application.properties in springboot in junit Test class? i don't want to use @Mock Annotation or initialize config class using constructor and set values using setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `SpringExtension`? You can simply put `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on top of your test class. Make sure the configuration properties bean you're trying to initialize is picked up by using `@ComponentScan` or `@ContextConfiguration.classes`.

You can also override production values by using a separate profile (e.g. `test`), creating an `application-test.properties` config file, and putting `@Profiles("test")` on top of the test class.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid the tediousness of preparing nested mocks for your configuration properties class, you might want to try [deep stubbing](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-fluent-apis).